# Composer install is not checking composer.json

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I have my composer.json with Guzzle 6.5.2 with Laravel Framework 6.20.30

But when I run composer install or composer update, it install the Guzzle 6.5.5, Why? If I am saying that it's 6.5.2?

```
{
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"type": "project",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": [
    "framework",
    "laravel"
],
"license": "MIT",
"require": {
    "php": "^7.2",
    "ahmedsaoud31/laravel-permission-to-vuejs": "dev-master",
    "barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "^0.9.0",
    "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.5.2",
    "laravel/framework": "^6.18.35",
    "laravel/passport": "^9",
    "laravel/tinker": "^2.0",
    "phpmailer/phpmailer": "^6.2",
    "sasco/libredte-sdk-php": "^1.1",
    "spatie/flysystem-dropbox": "^1.2",
    "spatie/laravel-backup": "^6.11",
    "srmklive/flysystem-dropbox-v2": "^1.0"
},
```

Comment: Please share more details. If you explicitly want to install v6.5.2, why not put that **exact** requirement in the composer.json?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `^` inside your version, it will update you to all future minor/patch versions, without incrementing the major version.

This means if you have `^6.5.2`, it will keep major version `6` and update to the latest update later than `5.2` (minor.patch version). This said, it update to the latest compatible version which currently is `6.5.5`.

If you want exact `6.5.2` then remove the caret symbol (^) from the beginning (which generally is not advised since you won't get later patches and updates).